# Preserve tabs when saving XML in AS3/FLex4/Air app

Tags: xml, apache-flex, tabs

I'm loading an xml file in AS3/Flex for an AIR app.  When I save it, the indenting looks pretty, however all the tabs from the original file, are now spaces.  Can I save to that the tabs remain?

open file code:

```
var file:File = event.target as File;
var fileStream:FileStream = new FileStream();
fileStream.open( file, FileMode.READ );

var fileContents:String = fileStream.readUTFBytes(
    fileStream.bytesAvailable );
fileStream.close();

XML.ignoreComments = false;
XML.ignoreWhitespace = false;
var newXML:XML = new XML(fileContents);

var scriptParent:XML = <xml></xml>;
scriptParent.appendChild(newXML);
data = new XMLListCollection(scriptParent.children());
```

save file code:

```
var stream:FileStream = new FileStream();
stream.open(currFileObject, FileMode.WRITE);
stream.writeUTFBytes(XML (data));
stream.close();
```

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up converting to a string and just replacing double spaces with tab.  I found a replace function by Colin Moock.

```
function saveData(event:Event):void 
{
    var newFile:File = event.target as File;
    var stream:FileStream = new FileStream();
    stream.open(newFile, FileMode.WRITE);
    var xString:String = data.toXMLString();
    var result = replace(xString, "  ", String.fromCharCode(9));
    stream.writeUTFBytes( (result));
    stream.close();
}

function replace (origStr, searchStr, replaceStr) {
    var tempStr = "";
    var startIndex = 0;
    if (searchStr == "") {
        return origStr;
    }
    if (origStr.indexOf(searchStr) != -1) {
        var  searchIndex = origStr.indexOf(searchStr, startIndex)
        while ( searchIndex != -1) {
            tempStr += origStr.substring(startIndex, searchIndex);
            tempStr += replaceStr;
            startIndex = searchIndex + searchStr.length;
            searchIndex = origStr.indexOf(searchStr, startIndex)

        }
        return tempStr + origStr.substring(startIndex);
    } else {
        return origStr;
    }
}
```